# Unable to fetch eml file contain in eml file using javamail API

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I have an `eml` file which contains another `eml` file as an attachment.

when I try to fetch attachment using `javaMail` API, `getDisposition` value indicates attachment but `file-Name` is `null`.
please anyone have an idea about root cause.

Comment: What is the difficulty in extracting the attachment. How are you extracting the attachments and what is the error you are getting?

Comment: There's no guarantee that attachments have file names.

Comment: @Bill, yes your right ..... I check  internet header of eml file , header  doesnt have file name for eml file. Do u know, why file name is missing for this file.

Comment: What's the file name for something that's never stored in a file?  The file name is not required and some mailers don't make up a file name in cases like this.